# ProgressBar with ring drawable appears as a line

Tags: android, layout

**EDIT: My mistake is quite stupid, sorry. I used `tools` prefix instead of `android` so I wasn't actually setting the `progressDrawable` at run time. I just get paranoid when something fails in android...**

I need a red progress circle on top of a grey circle (as a placeholder), both around an image.

The red progress circle appears correctly but the grey circle appears as a horizontal red line.

[image]

It's strange because each circle appears correctly if drawn alone, but when I want both circles at the same time one of them is broken.

This is the layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="13dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <!-- TODO: appears as a line, why? -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bg"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:max="1"
        android:progress="1"
        tools:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle_grey" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="70"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle_red" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And the circle drawables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="2dp"
    android:useLevel="true">
    <solid android:color="@color/red" />
</shape>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="2dp"
    android:useLevel="true">
    <solid android:color="@color/grey" />
</shape>
```

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you're not using it as a LevelListDrawable, can you remove the android:useLevel attribute and see if that does it? Also, on a sidenote, although the innerRadius should be defined by default, I would still recommend you to try specifying explicit values for the shapes just to see what can be done to fix this

Comment: For God's sake, I wrote `tools:progressDrawable` instead of `android:progressDrawable`!! Sorry for my stupid mistake.